# How to prevention from stop the playing music when close app

Tags: android

I make a android application for play sound.

I use the service for playing sound, however when close the app service stopped then music stopped.

Please help me

Comment: Is the service a bounded one?

Comment: What do you mean by 'when close the app'?
tapping back button or swiping it from recent app list or ...?

Comment: when swiping from recent app,Thanks

Comment: yes  Raghunandan , service is bounded.

Comment: Use Service not intent service

Comment: Omar Hassan,I use Service.

Comment: kindly put some source code here :-)

Comment: It will help a lot if you can show how the service is created and how you wrote the service into the manifest. But I was thinking that the service is not sticky and not running into another process with the `android:process=":otherProcess"`